# Resizing image с помощью php

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток, у меня возникла проблема при смене размера фото, у меня есть код, как меняет размер фото, на первой фото он сработал хорошо с размером 350х200, так же мне нужно чтобы он работал при размере 100х800, чтобы картинку не искривляло, а просто добавляли поля, а сама картинка чтобы была в центре, может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой

```
$size = array($source_width, $source_height); 
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h); 
        $src_aspect = $size[0] / $size[1]; 
        $thumb_aspect = $w / $h; 
        if($src_aspect < $thumb_aspect) {               
            $scale = $h / $size[1];
            $new_size = array($h * $src_aspect, $h);
            $src_pos = array(($size[0] * $scale - $w) / $scale / 2, 0); 
        } else {
           
            $new_size = array($w, $h);
            $src_pos = array(0,0);
        }
        $new_size[0] = max($new_size[0], 1);
        $new_size[1] = max($new_size[1], 1);
     
        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source_gdim, 0, 0, $src_pos[0], $src_pos[1], $new_size[0], $new_size[1], $size[0], $size[1]);
        imagejpeg($thumb, "images/photo/resize/"."$name"."($w"."x"."$h"." 1).");
        return $thumb;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Условие `$src_aspect < $thumb_aspect` определяет с каких сторон добавлять поля (с боков или сверху-снизу).

Эта часть кода считает поля с боков:

```
    if($src_aspect < $thumb_aspect) {      

        $scale = $h / $size[1];
        $new_size = array($h * $src_aspect, $h);
        $src_pos = array(($size[0] * $scale - $w) / $scale / 2, 0);
```

Так сделайте аналогично и для полей сверху и снизу (Тут так-же как и в первой части, только поменять местами высоту и ширину):

```
    } else {

        $scale = $w / $size[0];
        $new_size = array($w , $w* $src_aspect);
        $src_pos = array(0, ($size[1] * $scale - $h) / $scale / 2); 

    }
```

Comment: В алгоритме есть баг присмотритесь к условию, интересно человек сразу так отметил ответ как правильный :D

Comment: @Naumov вроде верно условие, что я упустил?

Comment: `$src_aspect = $size[0] / $size[1]; $thumb_aspect = $w / $h; ` а теперь )

Comment: @Naumov не ставьте загадки, напишите уже, что Вас смутило. Учтите, что размеры исходной картинки и получаемой не обязательно квадратные.

Comment: Да ёмоё ну видно же что отношение исходной картинки сравниваетcя и получаемой, а вы алгоритм пишите как будто сравниваете высоту и ширину. По это срабатывает вторая часть условия.

Comment: Я не могу понять, что вам не нравится. Если бы нужно было сделать квадратную картинку, я бы сравнил исходную высоту и ширину. Это частный случай когда w/h~1/1 => w~h